# Enable diagnostics for Azure Storage Account using PowerShell commands

Tags: azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-diagnostics

**How to enable Diagnostics for existing Azure Storage Account using PowerShell?**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerShell  to configure Storage Metrics in your storage account by using the cmdlet **Set-AzureStorageServiceMetricsProperty** to change the current settings.

Example 1:

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <your storageacount name>
Set-AzureStorageServiceMetricsProperty -MetricsType Minute -ServiceType Blob -MetricsLevel ServiceAndApi  -RetentionDays 5 -Context $context
```

I enabled the diagnostics like this:[enable Blob metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jRgd.png)

If you want to enable the below Blob,Table,Queue logs, you can use the cmdlet **Set-AzureStorageServiceLoggingProperty** to change the current settings.

Example 2:

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <your storageacount name>
Set-AzureStorageServiceLoggingProperty -ServiceType Queue -Context $context  -LoggingOperations read,write,delete -RetentionDays 5
```

I enabled the Queue logs like this:

[enable Queue logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWscy.png)

---

Update: If you just want to  enable storage of diagnostic logs in a storage account,use this command:

```
Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId [your resource id] -StorageAccountId [your storage account id] -Enabled $true
```

See more details about **Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting** ,refer to this:

learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/set-azurermdiagnosticsetting?view=azurermps-4.3.1

Comment: Hi Wayne, Thank you for reply. The commands that you have provided are SM commandlets. I am looking for Azure RM commands in Powershell. One thing I found that if I create a new Azure Storage Account, then by default Diagnostics are enabled. But, if there are any existing Storage Account's previously created, then no powershell commands available to update or enable diagnostics for Storage Account

Comment: Hi,@Amruta,I'm sure these scripts are all Azure RM powershell cmdlet.You can try it .See more details about  Set-AzureStorageServiceMetricsProperty tin this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageservicemetricsproperty?view=azurermps-4.3.1

Comment: See more details about Set-AzureStorageServiceLoggingProperty in this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-e2e-troubleshooting

Comment: Hi Wayne, Thank you for reply. The commands worked perfectly fine. Thank you. But  this command didn't work for me... $StorageAccountResourceId = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name $StorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName).Id
Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $StorageAccountResourceId -Enabled $True